# How do i consolidate multiple SQL update statements in a macro?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the following update statements which are execute via VBA. It seems to be sub-optimal to have multiple update statements. How do i consolidate these into a single statement? The statements update an Access database.

```
strSqlLoc = "UPDATE table1 AS type SET type.Value='" & Range("C" & i).Value & "' WHERE PropertyID=" & Range("B" & i).Value & ";"
strSqlEnv = "UPDATE table1 AS type SET type.Value='" & Range("E" & i).Value & "' WHERE PropertyID=" & Range("D" & i).Value & ";"
strSqlClass = "UPDATE table1 AS type SET type.Value='" & Range("G" & i).Value & "' WHERE PropertyID=" & Range("F" & i).Value & ";"

Set rs = cn.Execute(strSqlLoc)
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSqlEnv)
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSqlClass)
```

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but you might be able to write one long batch statement and execute the whole batch at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another Update**

For multiple row updates it looks like [Batch Update](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Access/PerformingBatchUpdates.htm) could do the trick.

```
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim strSQL As String
Dim lngUpdated As Long

rst.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
rst.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rst.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
rst.Open ("Select * from table1 ")

lngUpdated = 1

rst.Find "PropertyID=" & Range("B1")

Do Until rst.EOF
    rst("Value") = Range("C" & lngUpdated)
    lngUpdated = lngUpdated + 1
    rst.Find "PropertyID=" & Range("B" & lngUpdated), 1, adSearchForward
Loop

// Try repeating above for the other two columns?

rst.UpdateBatch

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Can't really get much better than this, unless the data you are updating is already somewhere in the DB. You could try the case statement technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162728/546375)

**Update:**

I think my intuition behind that batch upload thought was that if you can somehow get the data on the server side in one shot, you could then join on it and update another table in one update statement. if you are only updating three values - look into creating a query on access side and passing in your six parameters in a single call, then use the technique described [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1089259.aspx?UPDATE%20multiple%20ROWS%20with%20different%20Values%20with%20single%20statement%20Multiple%20Rows%20in%20subquery%20ORA%2001427) inside the query

Comment: Hmm, that would mean i would validate each record against the database before updating it. Wouldn't that place additional load and is it really necessary?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I believe you're correct about that.

Comment: you're right guys, I made some clarifying updates above

Comment: @Alex M - The intention is to upload it to the database in one go using Excel as the frontend. There will be more than 3 queries. Potentially up to 30 hence the want to optimize it.

Comment: made some updates with untested BatchUpdate attempt, probably far from the truth, but should give the idea