# How to handle large data in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a mysql database which contains data from api ,suppose it has a field called gameid which is unique ,every time a new data comes from API ,I run a query and select all gameid ,then with Array.Filter() method in JS(Node js) filter out the data which is not present in database and is there in API and store the unique data in database

Something Like

`let filtered_data=datafromapi.filter(data=>!mysqldata.includes(data.gameid))`

But With almost 30k records this takes a lot of time .Any idea how to do such process with mysql and node js.

Comment: What is the original format of the data returned by the API?

Comment: json format obviously.That's why I am using filter,and the data from mysql is also in json

Comment: Thats really Mysqls job ...

Comment: Not sure how using `Array.filter()` implies json without even knowing how far into the chain it is, but okay.

Comment: How ?? I have learnt about partioning in mysql but ,I believe that doesn't suits the situation @JonasWilms

Comment: I guess you want to [upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107752/how-to-perform-an-upsert-so-that-i-can-use-both-new-and-old-values-in-update-par) in a [batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322726/mysql-batch-insert-update-statements-in-single-query), but I never really used Mysql so I'm not sure if it's the way to go, thats how I'd do that in Mongodb

Comment: @ambianBeing that would be the preferrable way. It saves a ton of time due to less network data, along with more optimized paths at every step. The code is not fully visible so it's impossible to tell, but I'm ready to bet you can do the entire thing in a single SQL query (via `INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS`).

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Yeah, sorry I deleted my comment because it didn't really add any value unless we know more from OP. You stated it much better/clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment of Jonas ,the `upsert` is the most suitable process which can allow you to avoid inserting `duplicate data` or probably the `error encountered for duplicate records`. As an example-

You can have a query like ,

```
insert into table_name values('your column values') on duplicate key update gameid = gameid
```

It will be  much easier and hassle free  of storing 30k records in memory and then filtering them. Moreover it will limit your concerns to database only.Link For Reference-[dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over a few of the requirements and observable rules of your code from that one line of code:

- You're receiving something that eventually maps into an array of structures as follows:

  ```
  {
    "data": ["game_ids"]
  }
  ```
- You want to filter based on contents of another array, `mysqldata`.

Assuming you *cannot* change the return format of the API, you can leverage a property of your data to optimize at least sone of it.

Your API return is a list of independent objects. You can take this to your advantage, as you will only need to perform one operation on each to filter. If you can get your API call to return a `Reader` as opposed to a readily-parsed JSON object, you can take advantage of this by using a [streaming json parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json) as opposed to `JSON.parse`.

This type of parser will return a stream of tokens, as it filters through your array, as opposed to doing the filtering then returning everything in one chunk.

This will not massively increase the performance, since the largest part of your code's clock time will be spent waiting for the network request to complete and the filtering itself (30k calls to `Array.includes()`, all of them impossible to avoid), so don't expect miracles.

## The better way

The better way of doing it is to change the API endpoint, if at all possible, since that'll allow you to solve two problems in one go: fewer data transferred over the network, and fewer clock cycles spent filtering.

What you are effectively doing is a client-side (to the database, that is) `WHERE gameid IN (...)`. If you are allowed to modify the API call, you should be taking this into account.

Comment: So I have to look into mysql way preferably.

Comment: If you want to avoid having to transfer a 30k-large object and doing the filtering, yes. If you cannot do that, however, look into the streaming parser to alleviate the parsing time a bit.